# Can I use a GeocodeServer on AGS in a python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, python-script-tool, geocoding-service

I'd like to write a script that will call out to 3 separate Geocode Services online and run a user defined CSV through them...

The CSV will contain records in three states and each state has a GeocodeServer:

VA: https://gismaps.vita.virginia.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Geocoding/VGIN_Composite_Locator/GeocodeServer

DE: https://firstmap.delaware.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Location/DE_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer

MD: http://geodata.md.gov/imap/rest/services/GeocodeServices/MD_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer

When I run a test I get an error saying the Geocode Service does not exist...

```
inputCSV = "//nas/geog/esrgc/projects_inprocess/esrgc/carbon_footprint/2017/fall/processing/fall2016students.csv"
addrLocator = "http://geodata.md.gov/imap/rest/services/GeocodeServices/MD_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer"
addrFields =  "Address1; City; State; Zip Code"
outClass = "//nas/geog/esrgc/projects_inprocess/esrgc/carbon_footprint/2017/fall/processing/fall2016students.shp"
arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding(inputCSV, addrLocator, addrFields, outClass, 'STATIC')
```

Is it even possible to use a Geocode Service on ArcServer as an input? arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding

I could just geocode these in ArcMap and continue the script from there for the rest of the analysis, but if I could get this to work it would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Geocode Addresses URL for that service: http://geodata.md.gov/imap/rest/services/GeocodeServices/MD_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses

Comment: Same error:

ERROR 000732: Input Address Locator: Dataset http://geodata.md.gov/imap/rest/services/GeocodeServices/MD_CompositeLocator/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (GeocodeAddresses).